# Error with AppleScript - Integer?

Tags: macos, integer, applescript

I have been making a simple script for my sister, but it does not work. It calls for an integer? I did not specify it in my program, but it calls it anyway...?

My Script:

```
     activate
     display dialog "Click Start to start importing your own kindle books!" with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang" buttons
 {"Cancel", "Start"} default button "Start"

     property documentFolder : "documents"

     tell application "Finder" to (get name of every disk whose ejectable is true)
     try
     set kindleLocation to Â¬
             ((choose from list result with prompt "Select your Kindle from the list:") as text)
     end try

     try
       set bookFiles to Â¬
             ((choose file with prompt Â¬
                   "Select kindle files to import:" of type {"public.html", "public.rtf", "com.microsoft.word.doc",
 "public.data.mobi", "public.plain-text", "com.adobe.pdf"} with
 multiple selections allowed) as text)
     end try

     display dialog "Please wait while the application copies the kindle books..." with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang"

     tell application "Finder"
       if not (exists folder documentFolder of kindleLocation) then
       make new folder at kindleLocation with properties {name:documentFolder}
       end if
     end tell

     set fullKindlePath to POSIX path of (kindleLocation as alias) & "documents"

     tell application "Finder"
      move (bookFiles) to fullKindlePath
     end tell

     display dialog "Process has been done! Please eject your kindle and the files will be on the home screen of your Kindle." with title
 "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang"
```

And the result from running it:

```
     tell current application
      activate
     end tell
     tell application "AppleScript Editor"
      display dialog "Click Start to start importing your own kindle books!" with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang" buttons
 {"Cancel", "Start"} default button "Start"
       -- {button returned:"Start"}
     end tell
     tell application "Finder"
      get name of every disk whose ejectable = true
       -- {"JEREMY DISK"}
     end tell
     tell application "AppleScript Editor"
      choose from list {"JEREMY DISK"} with prompt "Select your Kindle from the list:"
       -- {"JEREMY DISK"}
      choose file with prompt "Select kindle files to import:" of type {"public.html", "public.rtf", "com.microsoft.word.doc",
 "public.data.mobi", "public.plain-text", "com.adobe.pdf"} with
 multiple selections allowed
       -- {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:JeremyZhang:Downloads:5 ETS SAT S.pdf"}
      display dialog "Please wait while the application copies the kindle books..." with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang"
       -- {button returned:"OK"}
     Result:
     error "Canât make \"documents\" into type integer." number -1700 from "documents" to integer
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you please correct me?
AppleScript Editor V: 2.5 (138)
AppleScript 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a somewhat misleading error. It's telling you that documentFolder is the wrong type. But there are a couple other issues with the script, too. This version should work -- see comments, but try running this as is (I removed the option-return continuation character you were using; I suspect it doesn't translate well on this forum) :

```
activate
display dialog "Click Start to start importing your own kindle books!" with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang" buttons {"Cancel", "Start"} default button "Start"

property documentFolder : "documents"

tell application "Finder" to (get name of every disk whose ejectable is true)
try
    set kindleLocation to ((choose from list result with prompt "Select your Kindle from the list:") as text)
    --display dialog class of kindleLocation -- class is text
end try

try
    set bookFiles to ((choose file with prompt "Select kindle files to import:" of type {"public.html", "public.rtf", "com.microsoft.word.doc", "public.data.mobi", "public.plain-text", "com.adobe.pdf"} with multiple selections allowed) as text)
end try

display dialog "Please wait while the application copies the kindle books..." with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang"

tell application "Finder"
    --coerce kindleLocation to alias
    if not (exists folder documentFolder of alias kindleLocation) then
        make new folder at kindleLocation with properties {name:documentFolder}
    end if
end tell
--don't use posix ... but you already have variables to build this
--set fullKindlePath to (kindleLocation) & ":documents:"--could've done this, but you don't need this, you can use same construction as above

tell application "Finder"
    move (bookFiles) to folder documentFolder of alias kindleLocation
end tell

display dialog "Process has been done! Please eject your kindle and the files will be on the home screen of your Kindle." with title "Kindle Book Uploader by Jeremy Zhang"
```